# How to force wxMaxima to calculate subfunctions?

Tags: maxima-software

I have the following code:

```
B1(a,b,c,d) := (1-c) + (1-b) $
B2(a,b,c,d) := -(1-c) * (1-b) $
B3(a,b,c,d) := c*d + b*a $
B4(a,b,c,d) := -c*d*(1-b) - b*a*(2-c) $
B5(a,b,c,d) := b*a*(1-c) $
_estP(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) := x1*PTL1 + x2*PTL2 + x3*DTL1 + x4*DTL2 + x5*DTL3 $
estP(a,b,c,d) := _estP( B1(a,b,c,d), B2(a,b,c,d), B3(a,b,c,d), B4(a,b,c,d), B5(a,b,c,d));
quadrat(a,b,c,d) := ((PTL0 - estP(a,b,c,d))/(b*c))^2;
```

now I want to see the result of my calculation, i.e. a function of a, b, c and d.

but all I see is precisely what I typed (but formatted) - "quadrat(a,b,c,d):=((PTL0-estP(a,b,c,d))/(b*c))^2", meaning wxmaxima still uses my subfunctions like estP instead of performing full calculation.

I'd be thankful for any tip showing me how to get the result in a neat form (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

I copied your definitions into wxMaxima and at the end I typed quadrat(a,b,c,d); and I got:

(-(1-b)*(c-1)*PTL2-(-c-b+2)*PTL1+PTL0-a*b*(1-c)*DTL3-(-(1-b)*c*d-a*b*(2-c))*DTL2-(c*d+a*b)*DTL1)^2/(b^2*c^2)

which is probably what you are looking for :)